# Como usar o bootstrap no spring boot de forma correta

Tags: java, html5, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

Olá galera sou novo no Spring Boot e estou com dificuldade em algumas coisas relacionado a Spring + BootStrap eu tenho uma aplicação que eu coloco http://localhost:8082/funcionarioCadastrar ele funciona normal, a pagina vem toda como fiz no bootstrap mas quando ele coloco http://localhost:8082/funcionarioCadastrar/{id} ou seja sudo que coloco depois da segunda barra ele mostra a pagina toda desformatada com erro 404 já verifiquei em tudo e não consigo resolver quem poder me ajudar agradeço

### Config

```
package com.farmacia;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/scss/**", "/vendor/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/error","/funcionarioCadastrar").permitAll()
            /*.antMatchers("/funcionarioCadastrar","/funcionarioExcluir","/medicamentoExcluir" ,"/clienteExcluir"
                    ).hasRole("ADMIN")*/
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception{
         return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
    }

}
```

### Main

```
package com.farmacia;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


@SpringBootApplication
public class FarmaciaxApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(FarmaciaxApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FarmaciaxApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Controller

```
package com.farmacia.web;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.farmacia.model.User;
import com.farmacia.repository.UserRepository;
import com.farmacia.service.SecurityService;
import com.farmacia.service.UserService;
import com.farmacia.validator.UserValidator;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;
    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidater;

    // Método logar no sistema
    @GetMapping({ "/", "/login" })
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Login e/ou senha invalidos");
        }else {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Login realizado com sucesso,Bem vindo!");
        }
        if (logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Logout realizado com sucesso!");
        }
        System.out.println(error);
        return "login";
    }

    // Buscar Funcionarios
    @GetMapping("/funcionarioBuscar")
    public ModelAndView listar(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userRepository.findAll());
        return new ModelAndView("   funcionarioBuscar", model);
    }
    // pré cadastra
    @GetMapping("/funcionarioCadastrar")
    public String funcionarioCadastrar(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return "/funcionarioCadastrar";
    }
    // Cadastrar
    @PostMapping("/funcionarioCadastrar")
    public String salvar(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/funcionarioCadastrar";
        }

        userService.save(user);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("message", "Funcionario salvo com sucesso.");
        return "redirect:/funcionarioCadastrar";
    }
```

### properties

```
server.port:8082
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/farmacia?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Farmacia XYZ</title>
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="page-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-1" th:href="@{index}">Farmacia XYZ</a>
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-white order-1 order-sm-0" id="sidebarToggle" >
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- Navbar pesquisar -->
    <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-append">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ml-md-0">
      <li class="visible-xs">
         <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
             <button type="submit" class="log2 btn btn-default text-white" ><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Sair</button>
         </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
          <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
          <span>Medicamentos</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Menu Medicamentos</h6>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/medicamentoCadastrar}">Cadastrar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/medicamentoBuscar}">Buscar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/medicamentoAlterar}">Alterar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/medicamentoExcluir}">Deletar</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
          <span>Funcionarios</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Menu Funcionarios</h6>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/funcionarioCadastrar}">Cadastrar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/funcionarioBuscar}">Buscar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/funcionarioAlterar}">Alterar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/funcionarioExcluir}">Deletar</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
          <span>Clientes</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Menu Clientes</h6>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="@{/clienteCadastrar}">Cadastrar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="@{/clienteBuscar}">Buscar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="@{/clienteAlterar}">Alterar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="@{/clienteExcluir}">Deletar</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Funcionarios</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
            Funcionarios</div>
            <div th:if="${message != null}">
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <span th:text="${message}">message</span>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
           </div>
          <div class="card-body">

            <form th:action="@{/cadastrarFuncionario}" th:method="${user.id} == null ? post : put" th:object="${user}">
              <div class="form-row">
                <input id="id" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"   />
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="username">Login</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="Login de usuário"/>
                  <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="password">Senha</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Senha"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Nome">
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputCity">Salario</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" name="salary" th:field="*{salary}"  placeholder="Ex... 998.00" /> 
                </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputAddress2">CPF</label>
                  <input maxlength="11" type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf" th:field="*{cpf}" placeholder="CPF"/>
                   <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cpf')}" th:errors="*{cpf}" class="label label-danger"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="roles">Perfil</label>
                  <input maxlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" id="roles" name="name" th:field="*{roles}" placeholder="admin , user"/>
                   <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('roles')}" th:errors="*{roles}" class="label label-danger"></div>
                  <!-- 
                  <select th:field="*{roles}" class="form-control" id="roles" >
                        <option th:text="${roles.name}" th:value="${roles.id}" th:each="roles: ${roles}"></option>
                  </select>
                   -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
              <a th:href="@{/funcionarioCadastrar}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Atualizado Hoje 03/05</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid --
      <!-- Sticky Footer -->
      <footer class="sticky-footer">
        <div class="container my-auto">
          <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
            <span>Copyright © Farmacia XYZ 2019</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>
  <!-- Logout Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Deseja realmente sair?</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Selecione "Sair" abaixo se você estiver pronto para terminar sua sessão atual.</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <a class="btn btn-primary">Sair</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi o problema, mas se vc quer acessar uma rota como `rota/{id}`, então no seu controller vc precisa de um `@RequestMapping("rota/{id}")` e aí usar um `@PathVariable("id") int id` no parâmetro do método.

Comment: Muito obrigado o problema era esse mesmo valeu!

Comment: Legal, vou colocar como resposta, beleza? Aí vc marca como certa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer acessar a rota `rota/{id}` então você precisa mapear essa rota no seu controller.
Algo como:

```
@RequestMapping("rota/{id}")
public String rota(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    //corpo
}
```